# multiple optional conditions in query + active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I m using rails 3.1.11 with mysql. Consider a User(name, role, city) and Project(name) model . I want to collect users with role 'admin' from 'Pune' **or** 'manager' from 'Mumbai'.

```
User
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, uniq: true

Project
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, uniq: true
```

the query that use is

```
users = []
users <<  User.where(role: 'admin', location: 'Pune') 
users <<  User.where(role: 'manager', location: 'Mumbai')
Project.first.users << users
```

which fires 2 queries. How can i collect the above data in a single call? Mongoid has **any_of** for similar queries. http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#any_of. I wouldnt prefer to collect all users and then filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
User.where(["(role = ? and location = ?) or (role = ? and location = ?)", 'admin', 'Pune', 'manager', 'Mumbai'])
```

Comment: i dont want to use mysql syntax in app.

Comment: This is not `MySQL` specific syntax .

Answer (score 0):

If you use the squeel gem, you can make this much nicer:

```
User.where{(role = 'admin') & (location = 'Pune') | (role = 'manager') & (location = 'Mumbai')}
```

The curly braces signal the use of squeel, which also provides the & and | operators for AND and OR.
I think this looks much easier to read and maintain.